# Firebird and Entity Framework Error -804 Unknown data type

Tags: c#, exception, entity-framework-6, firebird2.1

I'm trying to get specific data from db with this code

```cs
Bunts = _buntRepository.Bunts
            .Where(b => !steel.HasValue || b.SteelCode == steel)
            .OrderBy(b => b.CreationTime)
            .Skip((page - 1) * _pageSize)
            .Take(_pageSize)
```

Entity framework generates this SQL statement for it:

```sql
SELECT FIRST (5) SKIP (0)
"B"."BUNTCODE" AS "BUNTCODE", 
"B"."BUNTNAME" AS "BUNTNAME", 
"B"."BUNTDIAM" AS "BUNTDIAM", 
"B"."BUNTSTEEL" AS "BUNTSTEEL", 
"B"."BUNTCREATETIME" AS "BUNTCREATETIME"
FROM ( SELECT 
"D"."BUNTCODE" AS "BUNTCODE", 
"D"."BUNTNAME" AS "BUNTNAME", 
"D"."BUNTDIAM" AS "BUNTDIAM", 
"D"."BUNTSTEEL" AS "BUNTSTEEL", 
"D"."BUNTCREATETIME" AS "BUNTCREATETIME"
FROM "BUNTS" AS "D"
WHERE (("D"."BUNTSTEEL" = @p__linq__1) OR (("D"."BUNTSTEEL" IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))
)  AS "B"
ORDER BY "B"."BUNTCREATETIME" ASC
```

This code throws exception with text

> Dynamic SQL Error.
>   SQL error code = -804.
>   Data type unknown.

Same does IBExpert. Seems like something wrong with @p__linq__1 parameter. How do I solve this problem?

I'm using Firebird 2.1.6.18547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated uses `@p__linq__1 IS NULL` (which is actually sent as `? IS NULL` to the server), and this was only [introduced in Firebird 2.5](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-sqlnull.html).

To be able to use this you either need to upgrade to Firebird 2.5, or handle the `steel.HasValue` condition in code and not in the query as:

```
var query _buntRepository.Bunts
if (steel.HasValue) 
{
    query = query.Where(b => b.SteelCode == steel)
}
Bunts = query.OrderBy(b => b.CreationTime)
    .Skip((page - 1) * _pageSize)
    .Take(_pageSize);
```

NOTE: The above doesn't confirm to the generated query (which seems to be a bug). If you want the result as generated then you need:

```
if (steel.HasValue) 
{
    query = query.Where(b => b.SteelCode == steel.Value)
}
else 
{
    query = query.Where(b => b.SteelCode == null)
}
```

Comment: Well, seems like it really doesnt want to handle nullable types properly. Can you enlighten me where can i read about those problems related with using FB 2.1 and EF I will meet in the future? Or should I just upgrade to 2.5 and dont care?

Comment: @Pallaris I'd suggest you upgrade to 2.5.

Comment: You may need to take `steel.Value` out of the Where as well by first assigning it to a local variable.

Comment: can you give me an advice of which approach is best for using nullable parameters: 1. Check in the code if it really has value, and if so - build up .Where(x => ...) statement 2. Build .Where statement in any case like .Where(x => param == null || param.Value == fieldCode.Value)

Comment: @Pallaris The first will probably perform slightly better.